# Conditional formatting in Excel for similar dates in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I need some help with conditional formatting where Sheet 1 has dates in a row (kindly refer "Image Sheet 1") and Sheet 2 has a list of Dates in "column A", I want to apply a conditional formatting in all the dates in Sheet 1 where if a Date in Sheet 1 is equal to a Date in Sheet 2 the whole Date column in sheet one be coloured Grey, the asterisk the blanks below every date should be coloured grey too.

Could someone please help me with this?

[image: Image Sheet 1]

[image: Image Sheet 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select columns ( from E to P )
- Add CF rule: Home > Conditional Formatting > New rule

`=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,E$1)>0`

[image]